# URL redirect in Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails application, for some reason, I have to redirect my URL in to desired URL.

This is how my config setting the `routes.rb`.

`map.connect 'sample/:action/:id.:format', :controller => 'test'`

1. It redirects well when the url is http://example.com/sample. It goes `Test` controller index method.
2. When the url is http://example.com/sample/displayname?id=10, it goes to `Test` controller and searches for `displayname` method. Obviously it wasn't there, so I got the "`undefined`" error message.
   Here I want even though the URL is (http://example.com/sample/displayname?id=10) it quite enough to go `Test` controller's index method.
3. Also in the Address Bar I want to URL masking . If I hit http://example.com/sample/  it should redirect & in address Bar http://example.com/test.

How can i do this with Rails-2 application (Rails version 2.3.9)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't recommend doing this.  It's going against the conventions of how things are done in rails, and that tends to lead to pain.

(As for what I do recommend?  Just structure your urls differently.  If you do things the way rails makes easy, then you'll have fun using it.  Otherwise, your life will be full of pain and suffering.)

BUT, if you really want to, it looks like you can't do regular expression routes in rails.  I thought you could, but I see no signs that you can.  What you can do, however, is...

```
def method_missing
  index
end
```

Put that in the controller you want to have this behavior.  It'll do what you want, but it also might hide other errors.  In any case, don't say I didn't warn you.  This seems like a bad idea...

As for the redirect, a `before_filter` in the test controller will do that.

```
before_filter :redirect_if_wrong_path

def redirect_if_wrong_path
  if request.path =~ /\/sample/
    redirect_to request.path.sub('/sample', '/test')
  end
end
```

Comment: If this answer satisfies your needs, it's good form to accept it.  If not, let me know and I'll do my best to help you out, so that it does.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, unfortunately.  Could you phrase it differently?

Comment: I just improved the answer a bit.  Make sure to take the new redirect line into consideration when testing.